# TCP Socket connections in c# closes automatically

Tags: c#, tcp, asp.net-web-api2, iis-8, asyncsocket

I have a TCP socket programming code which runs in WebApi 2.0 , I created a socket pool which has collection of connected sockets to Remote host.. I have also implemented a polling mechanism with Remote TCP host

When I run it from my workstation ( PC ) via Visual Studio , Socket pool is always open and Polling continues with no issues

But when I host it in Server 2012 in IIS, it stops exactly after an hour. I don't know how to start debugging or how to check the differences in behavior. Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: check application pool idle timeout

Comment: @levent thanks so much for the comment, I made it to 0 and it works fine.. never had a clue !!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the IIS App Pool may be getting recycled (thus dropping your connections) for some reason.  Take a look at this page for a number of potential things too look for: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johan/2007/05/16/common-reasons-why-your-application-pool-may-unexpectedly-recycle/

Comment: Thanks for looking into this , just checked and found that App pool in IIS 8 is set to 29 hours of auto recycling .. :(